# Pandas forcing columns to be based on the first `k` delimiter strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a file with content

```
2018 43 NFO BID_-324 dfs.DataNode X
2018 5  NFO dfs.FSNames BID_123  XX
2019 13 NFO BID_-398 dfs.DataNode  X X
2019 45 NFO dfs.DataNode BID_-324
2019 14 NFO BID_123 dfs.DataNode X
```

I want to load this into a dataframe such that first column is the first number second column is the second number and third column is the remaining entry.

```
df
     n1  n2                            data
0  2018  43     NFO BID_-324 dfs.DataNode X
1  2018   5     NFO dfs.FSNames BID_123  XX
2  2019  13  NFO BID_-398 dfs.DataNode  X X
3  2019  45       NFO dfs.DataNode BID_-324
4  2019  14      NFO BID_123 dfs.DataNode X
```

I tried with `df1 = pd.read_csv('test.log', sep=" ", header=None,names=['n1','n2','data'])`. but it does not give me correct format.  How can I force read_csv to use only the first 3 delimiter strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first read the data in as one column. Then use `Series.str.split` with limit `n=2` and `expand=True` to get your desired result:

```py
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
2018 43 NFO BID_-324 dfs.DataNode X
2018 5  NFO dfs.FSNames BID_123  XX
2019 13 NFO BID_-398 dfs.DataNode  X X
2019 45 NFO dfs.DataNode BID_-324
2019 14 NFO BID_123 dfs.DataNode X
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, header=None)
df = df[0].str.split(" ", n=2, expand=True)
df.columns = ['n1','n2','data']
```

```
     n1  n2                            data
0  2018  43     NFO BID_-324 dfs.DataNode X
1  2018   5     NFO dfs.FSNames BID_123  XX
2  2019  13  NFO BID_-398 dfs.DataNode  X X
3  2019  45       NFO dfs.DataNode BID_-324
4  2019  14      NFO BID_123 dfs.DataNode X
```